# Solving a certain congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, let $x$ and $r$ be natural numbers and suppose that
$$x\cdot p \equiv p^p \pmod{p^r},$$
where $ 1 \leq r \leq p $ and $x \neq 0$.

Let $S_r = \{ x \mid x\cdot p \equiv p^p \pmod{p^r} \}$. Then there are $p$ $S_r$s.

The trivial $S_r$ is when $r=1$; as such, for all prime $p$, $S_1 =\mathbb{N}$,

Is this true that $S_r = \{x \mid (\exists q\in\Bbb N)(x= p^{r-1}\cdot q)\}$?

Can we have a solution $x$ such that $x \notin S_r$? If not, then it is true.

Comment: This : $S_r = \{x |x= p^{r-1}\cdot q$    $ \forall $  $q \in \mathbb{N}\}$  looks weird, to say the least. That quantifier and $\,\Bbb N\;$ don't seem to belong there.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I edited the question with my own guess about what might have been intended.

Comment: Keneth Adrian, I strongly suggest that you look at the current $\LaTeX$ code now that I have edited it; you will learn one or two things.

Comment: @dfeuer , that's what I assumed. Look at my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xp=p^p\pmod{p^r}\iff xp=p^p+kp^r\;,\;k\in\Bbb Z\iff $$

$$\iff x=p^{p-1}+kp^{r-1}=p^{r-1}\left(p^{p-r}+k\right)$$

Just put then $\,q=p^{p-r}+k\;$ ...